# Using CSS with javascript/Ajax function

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

`mypage()` is a long function which returns the page number, number of pages, next page etc’ (similar to pagination).

`selectPage()` is a javascript/Ajax script which send to the server the current page number.

My CSS file present me the `‘hover’` color of the page number but ignore of the `‘current’` color of the page number.

What is the correct syntax to write the CSS file for `‘current’`.

```
function mypage($total, $start) {  
;
; 
$mypage.= "<li><a href='javascript:selectPage(".$counter.")'>$counter</a></li>";
;
;
return $mypage;
}
```

The CSS file:

```
ul.mypage li a:hover, ul.mypage li a.current
{
   color:#AAA;
}
```

Comment: add the class current to your link

Comment: Could you reply with the full syntax because I try 
<li><a href class='javascript:selectPage(".$counter.")'>$counter</a></li>
and now also ‘hover’ is being ignored

Comment: because your that makes no sense. <li><a class='current' href='javascript:selectPage(".$counter.")'>$counter</a></li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sven's comment, the link needs a class of `current`

```
function mypage($total, $start) {  
  return "<li><a class='current' href='javascript:selectPage(".$counter.")'>$counter</a></li>";
}
```

If you want to add current when something is clicked, there's more work involved:

- In event handler: `this.className='current'` but you also need to remember the one that had current previously and remove it

Comment: Works! Thank you all for returning to me. Thank you Juan Mendes for your quick and effectively solution.

Comment: @user1315169 You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the arrow next to the up/down arrows